# How to make a customized compass view in android

Tags: android, android-view, digital-compass

I am working with a simple compass application. I need to set the compass view with the sensor activity for that i choose a compass view class. But it is only drawing a circle and a line for the compass view. I need to customize this view by replacing this circle and line with my own drawable images somebody please help me to fix this.

**My view class**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.view.View;

public class MyCompassView extends View {

  private Paint paint;
  private float position = 0;

  public MyCompassView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
  }

  private void init() {
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(2);
    paint.setTextSize(25);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    int xPoint = getMeasuredWidth() / 2;
    int yPoint = getMeasuredHeight() / 2;

    float radius = (float) (Math.max(xPoint, yPoint) * 0.6);
    canvas.drawCircle(xPoint, yPoint, radius, paint);
    canvas.drawRect(0, 0, getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredHeight(), paint);

    // 3.143 is a good approximation for the circle
    canvas.drawLine(xPoint,
        yPoint,
        (float) (xPoint + radius
            * Math.sin((double) (-position) / 180 * 3.143)),
        (float) (yPoint - radius
            * Math.cos((double) (-position) / 180 * 3.143)), paint);

    canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(position), xPoint, yPoint, paint);
  }

  public void updateData(float position) {
    this.position = position;
    invalidate();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The above code has been deprecated . an updated code is available [here](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-compass-code-example.html)

**XML Layout activty_main**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvHeading"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Heading: 0.0" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewCompass"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvHeading"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/img_compass" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {

    // define the display assembly compass picture
    private ImageView image;

    // record the compass picture angle turned
    private float currentDegree = 0f;

    // device sensor manager
    private SensorManager mSensorManager;

    TextView tvHeading;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // 
        image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.main_iv);

        // TextView that will tell the user what degree is he heading
        tvHeading = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvHeading);

        // initialize your android device sensor capabilities
        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // for the system's orientation sensor registered listeners
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION),
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        // to stop the listener and save battery
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

        // get the angle around the z-axis rotated
        float degree = Math.round(event.values[0]);

        tvHeading.setText("Heading: " + Float.toString(degree) + " degrees");

        // create a rotation animation (reverse turn degree degrees)
        RotateAnimation ra = new RotateAnimation(
                currentDegree, 
                -degree,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, 
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
                0.5f);

        // how long the animation will take place
        ra.setDuration(210);

        // set the animation after the end of the reservation status
        ra.setFillAfter(true);

        // Start the animation
        image.startAnimation(ra);
        currentDegree = -degree;

    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        // not in use
    }
}
```

Comment: Answers that are little more than a link are not considered good answers, and are better as comments.  If you want to add some more details, specifically the code and how to implement the solution, then it would be a better answer.

Comment: I'm using this compass code in the app I'm creating and need some help editing to make it work for my app. Could you check my question and try to help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22724671/how-to-point-a-compass-to-a-given-bearing-angle